# return to servlet in clustered environment

Tags: java, servlets, http-redirect, tomcat9

I have a simple question. I would expect that

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader(“Location”, httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString())
```

would return to itself. But within our clustered infrastructure with IIS and multiple TOMCAT's

```
httpServletRequest.getRequestURL()
```

points to IIS (clustermanager). Is this correct behaviour, because I'm not sure? The redirect fails at the moment.
I do understand that I could use a relative address (and that works), but I just would like to know if the observed behaviour (redirect fails) is as expected?

Comment: If you're running multiple Tomcat instances behind something like a load balancer, then in general you don't know which Tomcat instance would be hit on the return request.  In that environment, though, you would ideally have your Tomcat instances being fairly stateless, so it wouldn't matter which one gets hit.  If you really need to return to the same Tomcat instance, there are things like sticky sessions, but those have caveats.

Comment: agreed, but I also would expect transparancy. Following the same reasoning I do not care how this is done (redirect). So requesting to return to itself could be translated by the cluster manger to a request to one of the clustered instances (if server is stateless) and that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect sends a response to the client (browser), effectively asking the browser to send a completely new request.

The consequence of that is that the route will be followed from scratch. If there are reverse proxies and load balancers in front of the application server, then there are chances of the redirect going to a different instance of the application (a different cluster member).

To send the request to a different resource in the same application on the same server, use `forward` instead of sending a redirect:

```
httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(httpServletRequest.getContextPath())
       .forward(request, response);
```

The above code will theoretically send the request to the same servlet instance.

> The redirect fails at the moment.

There are many possible reasons for this to fail. The most likely is that your reverse proxy (IIS) is using local network addresses to talk to your application server (such as an internal IP address in the `Host` header, etc.). You may need to redirect to the host name as originally used by the browser (if domain name is known, or you could make your reverse proxy forward the `Host` header somehow). Some reverse proxies/web servers support rewriting.

Comment: Are you sure that forwarding a request can logically see a Tomcat instance behind a load balancer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, that's not my point. Forwarding remains in the same application instance (wherever it is, i.e., already behind proxies). It doesn't go to a different server.

Comment: I get it...my servlet API knowledge is not so current +1.

Comment: true. Your reasoning is correct up to the point to use a forward. The redirect is necessary for the browser history, something you can't accomplish with a forward (internal within server).

Comment: @user2767718 I've edited to comment more specifically about the failed redirect. Can you perhaps explain why you need it to be a redirect or why you need the browser to record distinct history entries?

Comment: We are using a PRG pattern. The redirect follows a POST.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds acceptable. Thank you. Sorry, but I do not have much knowledge about clustered environments/infrastructures. I will accept your answer. Thank you.